# ¿Como generar un conjunto de fechas a partir de un rango?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento calcular los días de un rango de fechas, tengo algo de este estilo, sin embargo me saca los la cantidad del rango, mi objetivo es que saque el numero del día correspondiente al mes.

**Lo que hace**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Objetivo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT NOMBRE,RFC,CURP,
DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(LEFT(FECHA,8) AS DATE),
CAST(RIGHT(FECHA,8) AS DATE))DIAS FROM TABLA
```

La fecha esta de esta forma '2018010120180131' por esa razón extraigo.

Comment: o sea, vos queres construir datos en una tabla, basado en registros que no existen. con un query o con un procedimiento? porque no se si vas a poder con un query

Comment: Seria meramente una idea, para posteriormente realizar un procedimiento.

Comment: A que queres llegar construyendo esta tabla? no tiene mucho sentido una tabla asi

Comment: Obtener los días de cada rango, para n cantidad de personas.

Comment: Pero el primer query ya te devuelve la cantidad de dias.. si es para solucionar un problema de la vista, deberia solucionarlo la vista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idealmente, como ya te ha comentado gbianchi, estos problemas se deberían resolver en la capa de vistas y no en la de negocios, sin embargo, entiendo que a veces esto no es posible.

Ayudaría mucho que tuvieras una tabla de fechas por cada día, con lo cual un simple `LEFT JOIN` a la misma resolvería tu problema. Como entiendo que no la tienes, la alternativa es generarla dinámicamente. Aquí la prueba de concepto:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
  Nombre VARCHAR(255),
  Fecha VARCHAR(16)
)

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Nombre, Fecha) VALUES ('LAURA', '2018010120180131')

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS N UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION 
    SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
)    
SELECT E.*,
       DATEADD(DAY, N.RN-1 , CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(E.Fecha,8)))
       FROM Ejemplo E
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.N) AS RN
                    FROM CTE T1
                    CROSS JOIN CTE T2
                    CROSS JOIN CTE T3
              ) N
       WHERE DATEADD(DAY, N.RN-1, CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(E.Fecha,8))) <= CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(E.Fecha,8))

DROP TABLE Ejemplo
```

#### Explicación:

- Primero que nada hay que generar una secuencia de número para poder generar cada fecha, hay muchas técnicas, en este ejemplo usamos una `COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION` recursiva para que mediante `CROSS JOINS` podamos generar una `X` cantidad de filas, en este caso al ser 10 filas por tres recursiones nos habilita a generar unas 1000 filas, agregando más `CROSS JOINs` multiplicamos los valores, pero obviamente siempre deberemos trabajar con un límite
- Con `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.N)` generamos el numerador de 1 a 1000
- Luego simplemente lo aplicamos a la tabla real mediante otro `CROSS JOIN` y vamos generando cada fecha simplemente sumándole el numerador a la fecha inicial y verificando no pasarnos del límite
- **Importante:** Esto debiera funcionar correctamente a partir de SQL 2008, si no fuera el caso, seguramente hay que dejar de usar los CTE y emplear otra técnica similar

Comment: Excelente @Patricio Moracho , me fue de total ayuda, te agradezco mucho!!!