# calcular fechas entre rango de fechas sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Buen día, mi problema es el siguiente, necesito obtener las fechas entre un rango de fechas
ejemplo 2020-06-01 y 2020-06-08, cuales fechas estarían entre estas dos para luego hacer la consulta dia por dia

Lo necesito para hacer un reporte de ventas anuales,mensuales y diarias

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Qtzsp_VentasGraficadas] 
    @FechaIni DATETIME,
    @FechaFin DATETIME,
    @CodigoSucursal varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiasDiff int
    DECLARE @DiasDiffAnt int
    DECLARE @FechaIniAnt datetime
    DECLARE @FechaFinAnt datetime
    DECLARE @VentasAnioActual money
    DECLARE @VentasAnioAnterior money

    SET @DiasDiff = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaIni,@FechaFin))

    SET @FechaIniAnt = DATEADD(YYYY,-1,@FechaIni)
    SET @FechaFinAnt = DATEADD(YYYY,-1,@FechaFin)

    SET @DiasDiffAnt = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaIniAnt, @FechaFinAnt))

     --Borramos los datos de la tabla
     --TRUNCATE TABLE TemporalGraficaVentas

     --Calculamos las ventas del año actual

     IF @CodigoSucursal = 'T'
      BEGIN
       WHILE (@DiasDiff > 0) BEGIN

         SET @VentasAnioActual = (SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) AS Total FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIni) AND DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIni))
         SET @VentasAnioAnterior = (SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) AS TOTAL FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIniAnt) AND DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIniAnt))

         INSERT INTO TemporalGraficaVentas (VentasAnio2020, FechasDeVenta,VentasAnio2019,FechaDeVentaAnt,CodigoSucursal) VALUES 
         (@VentasAnioActual,DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIni),@VentasAnioAnterior,DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIniAnt),'T')

         SET @DiasDiff -= 1;

        END
       END
     ELSE
      BEGIN
        WHILE (@DiasDiff > 0) BEGIN
         SET @VentasAnioActual = (SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) AS Total FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIni) AND DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIni) AND CodigoSucursal = @CodigoSucursal)
         SET @VentasAnioAnterior = (SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) AS TOTAL FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIniAnt) AND DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIniAnt) AND CodigoSucursal = @CodigoSucursal)

         INSERT INTO TemporalGraficaVentas (VentasAnio2020, FechasDeVenta,VentasAnio2019,FechaDeVentaAnt,CodigoSucursal) VALUES 
         (@VentasAnioActual,DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIni),@VentasAnioAnterior,DATEADD(DAY,+1,@FechaIniAnt),@CodigoSucursal)

        END
       END

       SELECT * FROM TemporalGraficaVentas

END
```

es parte del código pero no me ha funcionado muy bien

Comment: Cristián, revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205930/como-generar-un-conjunto-de-fechas-a-partir-de-un-rango, creo que es básicamente lo que preguntas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo hice algo que quizá te funcione, lo que se me ocurrio fue hacer una tabla temporal y llenarla con los valores dentro de un while para luego hacer un select a dicha tabla y saber exactamente cuantas fechas habia entre las fechas que habia especificado, algo asi:

```
DECLARE @DIA DATE;

SET @DIA = CONVERT(DATE,'01/01/2020',103); /*LA FECHA INICIAL*/

CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (FECHA DATE);

WHILE(@DIA<CONVERT(DATE,'01/01/2021',103)) /*EN LA CONDICIÓN DEL WHILE LA FECHA FINAL*/
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal
    SELECT 
    @DIA
SET @DIA = DATEADD(DD,1,@DIA)
END
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Comment: Es lo que estaba buscando, asi tengo las fechas en el rango, solo que al momento de pasarlo al SP me dice un error de sintaxis en el guion

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "en el guión"?